# iOS 8 custom keyboard extension UIKeyboardType

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm building a iOS 8 custom keyboard and I'd like the change the layout of the keyboard based on the UIKeyboardType, however, reading the keyboard type in UIInputViewController is always 0.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"TextInputMode: %ld", self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardType);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the `keyboardType` in InputView Delegate Methods Instead of ViewDidLoad . Because you can't get the keyboardType until The keyboard is fully presented and the input object is activated .

```
- (void)textWillChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {

    NSLog(@"TextInputMode: %ld", self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardType);

}
```

OR

```
- (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {

    NSLog(@"TextInputMode: %ld", self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardType);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

(not enough rep to add a comment sorry)

`textDidChange` is the best method to use because the keyboardType has been updated when this is called. If you use `textWillChange` you will find that your keyboard lags behind by one type.

Comment: This helped me!  Thanks!