# iOS swift Custom keyboard not detecting keyboardType

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am implementing Custom keyboard by sub-classing UIInputViewController.

i want to implement keyboard for emailAddress.

I have Xcode :- 8.1 iOS :-10.1 and swift version :- 3.0

I am trying code to find keyboardType

```
  textDocumentProxy.keyboardType?.rawValue
  (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).keyboardType?.rawValue
```

But this two lines alway giving 0 that is Default keyboard type.

any one help me please.

Comment: Is [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130932/ios-how-to-get-the-current-visible-keyboard-type/42131221#42131221) useful to your case?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579056/ios-8-custom-keyboard-extension-uikeyboardtype

Answer (score 0):

here textfield is object of class textfield.

```
textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

Comment: the question is related to extenson

Comment: sorry anshul but i want to find keyboard type, i am not want to change keyboard type.